# Controlling Raspberry PI zero device over the internet

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, java

I have five **Raspberry Pi zero W** devices and each device connected to 4 **channel relay module**. These five devices are in different locations and connected to the internet. We wrote a python program to control the relays by using SSH (console or remotely) and it works fine.

**My main objective is to control the relays over the internet by using a web browser and mobile apps.**

Give me any suggestions for the process.

Comment: Search about Django on raspberry pi. Check this link out: [Controlling Raspberry Pi with Django](https://medium.com/ristek-fasilkom/controlling-raspberry-pi-with-django-a91940fc3f4d)

Comment: There are many ways to do this. I'd recommend that you do more research, develop some ideas/approaches that you feel are suited to your situation, and formulate a more focused question. [This list of topics may be helpful.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 3):

Set up a simple REST-API with PHP for example that triggers local controlling code.
You may want to add some form of authentication tho like supplying a password in the request.

A request would be along the lines of:

```
http://pi1.domain.com/relay/on/1?pw=password
```